# Retrieve SharePoint 2010/2013 workflows in SharePoint 2013 using CSOM

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, csom

I need to write CSOM Code to retrieve SharePoint 2010/2013 workflows. I am able to get 2013 workflows only. Below is the code:

```
WorkflowAssociationCollection workflowcollection = list.WorkflowAssociations;

Context.Load(workflowcollection);

context.ExecuteQuery();

foreach(WorkflowAssociation WFassociation in workflowcollection)

{

  workflowName = workflowName+ WFassociation.Name.ToString()+";";

}
```

This code only returns 2013 workflows. How do I retrieve 2010 workflows?

Answer (score 0):

Try using WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByBaseID as below

```
[list].WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByBaseID([workflow base ID]);
```

The above returns a SPWorkflowAssociation object, which can be used as a parameter to start the workflow. e.g. below:

```
[site].WorkflowManager.StartWorkflow([list item],[SPWorkflowAssociation], "<root />");
```